# Prenex form with two same variables versus equivalence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

The statement `∃x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))` is logically equivalent to `∃xP(x) ∨ ∃xQ(x)` according to the solution from this [quiz (Question 3)](https://math.berkeley.edu/~moody/math55/quiz2section102.pdf)

But converting `∃xP(x) ∨ ∃xQ(x)` to it's prenex form would result in `∃x∃y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))` according to the rewrite rules described [here (item 3)](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/sections/section_06_11.html).

Is `∃x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))` logically equivalent to `∃x∃y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))`? How can I show that?

Comment: Have you tried to consider the cases separately?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

If you accept that $$\begin{align}\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))&\iff (\exists x~P(x))\vee(\exists x~Q(x))\tag 1\\(\exists x~P(x))\vee(\exists x~Q(x))&\iff (\exists x~P(x))\vee(\exists y~Q(y))\tag 2\\(\exists x~P(x))\vee(\exists y~Q(y)) &\iff \exists x~\exists y~(P(x)\vee Q(y))\tag 3\end{align}$$

Then it follows that $$\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))\iff \exists x~\exists y~(P(x)\vee Q(y))\tag {4}$$

---

You seem to have trouble with (1) so here's a skeleton for a proof by cases

$${\fitch{\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))}{P(a)\vee Q(a)\\\fitch{P(a)}{~\\~}\\\fitch{Q(a)}{~\\~}\\(\exists x~P(x))\vee(\exists x~Q(x))}\\\fitch{(\exists x~P(x))\vee(\exists x~ Q(x))}{\fitch{\exists x~P(x)}{~\\~\\~}\\\fitch{\exists x~Q(x)}{~\\~\\~}\\\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))}\\\exists x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))\iff (\exists x~P(x))\vee(\exists x~ Q(x))}$$